# Reflection - object comparison & default values

Tags: c#, reflection, object-comparison

I'm trying to compare two complex objects in C#, and produce a Dictionary containing the differences between the two.

If I have a class like so:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public bool IsWhatever {get; set;}
    public string Something {get; set;}
    public int SomeOtherId {get; set;}
}
```

And one instance, thus:

```
var p = new Product
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        IsWhatever = false,
                        Something = "Pony",
                        SomeOtherId = 5
                    };
```

and another:

```
var newP = new Product
    {
        Id = 1,
        IsWhatever = true
    };
```

To get the differences between these, i'm doing stuff that includes this:

```
var oldProps = p.GetType().GetProperties();
var newProps = newP.GetType().GetProperties();

// snip 
foreach(var newInfo in newProps)
{
    var oldVal = oldInfo.GetValue(oldVersion, null);
    var newVal = newInfo.GetValue(newVersion,null);
}

// snip - some ifs & thens & other stuff
```

and it's this line that's of interest

```
var newVal = newInfo.GetValue(newVersion,null);
```

Using the example objects above, this line would give me a default value of 0 for `SomeOtherId` (same story for bools & DateTimes & whathaveyou).

What i'm looking for is a way to have `newProps` include only the properties that are explicitly specified in the object, so in the above example, `Id` and `IsWhatever`. I've played about with `BindingFlags` to no avail.

Is this possible? Is there a cleaner/better way to do it, or a tool that's out there to save me the trouble?

Thanks.

Comment: try [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) (free)...

Comment: There is no way to tell whether a property was explicitly initialized in that way. The CLR simply doesn't keep a track of that.

Comment: As far as I understood your task, you can't do this. You can't differentiate at runtime whether you created object by setting `bool` to false or whether it was set by default when object was created

Comment: You would neet to track in the constructor which properties were explicitly set, and which were defaulted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue without using reflection (or, not using it in this way at least).

It goes, more or less, like this:

```
public class Comparable
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> _cache;

    public Comparable()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Cache { get { return _cache; } }

    protected void Add(string name, object val)
    {
        _cache.Add(name, val);
    }
}
```

And the product implementation goes to this:

```
public class Product : Comparable
{
    private int _id;
    private bool _isWhatever;
    private string _something;
    private int _someOtherId;

    public int Id {get { return _id; } set{ _id = value; Add("Id", value); } }
    public bool IsWhatever { get { return _isWhatever; } set{ _isWhatever = value; Add("IsWhatever ", value); } }
    public string Something {get { return _something; } set{ _something = value; Add("Something ", value); } }
    public int SomeOtherId {get { return _someOtherId; } set{ _someOtherId = value; Add("SomeOtherId", value); } }
}
```

And the comparison is then pretty straightforward

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach(var obj in version1.Cache)
{
    foreach(var newObj in version2.Cache)
    {
        //snip -- do stuff to check equality
        dic.Add(....);
    }
}
```

Doesn't hugely dirty the model, and works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

There is no flag to tell if you a property was explicitly set. What you could do is declare your properties as nullable types and compare value to null.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did think of this, but i'd prefer not to dirty the objects in question with nullables. It could be my only option though. Thanks for the feedback in any case.

Comment: Well, sort of similar to that, but somewhat uglier would be to leave your type as not nullable and compare values to `default(T)`, but in that case `IsWhatever = false` would come up as not modified.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, this is what microsoft did with the xml wrapping classes, generated with the xsd utility, where you had a `XIsSpecified`, or something like that, for each property `X`.

So this is what You can do as well - instead of `public int ID{get;set;}`, add a private member `_id` , or whatever you choose to call it, and a boolean property `IDSpecified` which will be set to true whenever `Id`'s setter is called

Comment: Interesting - will leave the class declarations somewhat cluttered but might be the best option. Thanks for the suggestion.